# I could not able to get table properly when table(page break occurs) continues to the next page when dynamically creating table in VF

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I am created a table dynamically in apex and calling into the VF page, whenever table is long when it is moving to next page, I want it getS closed and create new header and repeat contents in next page. I am unable to do that in VF. Please help to achieve it.        [image]

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by adding -fs-table-paginate: paginate; line in the table style in VF page